# How do I combine dependant livedata objects into a single livedata object

Tags: android, kotlin

Here is an example of what I have to work with, I have two repositories one for homes and another for cars. The homes repository wraps a local sqlite db with a few tables. The cars repository is similar and has it's own sqlite db with different tables.

Homes DB

```
House Table
-----------
int id
string owner_first_name
int sqft
int floors
int car_id
```

Cars DB

```
Car Table
----------
int id
string make
string model
string nickname
int year
```

I'm trying to make two livedata functions in the house repository. One for returning an individual house and associated car nickname and another for returning a list of houses with the associated car nickname. I can add new methods to the car repository but I can't combine these repositories or databases, right now the only useful method from the car repository available is a `getCarLive(car_id: int) : LiveData<Car>` function.

I tried to use a map, call `getCarLive()`, and observe the result but the map returns before the observer is called so the carNick is never set.

```
getHouseLive(houseId: int) =
   houseDao.getHouseLive(houseId).map {
    val house_car_obj = HouseCar(it.id, it.sqft, it.owner_first_name)
    val observer = Observer<Car?> { c ->
       if (c != null) { house_car_obj.carNick = c.nickname }
    }
    val carLiveData = carRepository.getCarLive(it.car_id)
    carLiveData.observeForever(observer)
   }
   house_car_obj
}
```

I'm not sure what to try next, One thought was to return a nested LiveData, so I would structure the `HouseCar` like this

```
data class HouseCar(val id: int, val sqft: Int, val ownerName: String, val car: LiveData<car>)
```

Another thought I had was to make a non live data version of `suspend fun getCar()` in the car repository but then I need figure out how to call that from a background thread.

I tried searching but I only was able to find examples which combined different lists of objects into one list using MediatorLiveData. For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55044298/7100485) question on SO. The other problem with using MediatorLiveData is that I need the result of the first call to get the `car_id` before I can actually make the call to the second repository so I didn't know how to set that up with MediatorLiveData either.